# A simple bubble sort implementation in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I've written a Bubble Sort algorithm in Java and I want a review on these:

- Performance improvements.
- Code conventions.
- Algorithm design improvements.
- Cleaner approaches.

I would highly appreciate if you can review based on the points above, and I would prefer if you can add more points on top if it if you find necessary.

Here's the code:

```
package com.hassanalthaf.sortingalgorithms;

public class BubbleSort {

    private int temporary;

    public int[] sort(int[] numbers) {
        for (int mainIterations = 0; mainIterations < numbers.length; mainIterations++) {
            int comparisonsCount = (numbers.length - mainIterations) - 1;

            for (int comparisons = 1; comparisons < comparisonsCount; comparisons++) {
                if (numbers[comparisons] > numbers[comparisons + 1]) {
                    this.temporary = numbers[comparisons];
                    numbers[comparisons] = numbers[comparisons + 1];
                    numbers[comparisons + 1] = this.temporary;
                }
            }
        }

        return numbers;
    }

}
```

Here's my main class calling the `BubbleSort` sort method:

```
package com.hassanalthaf.sortingalgorithms;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {1, 20, 51, 12, 43, 2, 20};

        BubbleSort bubbleSort = new BubbleSort();

        numbers = bubbleSort.sort(numbers);

        for (int iterations = 0; iterations < numbers.length; iterations++) {
            System.out.println(numbers[iterations]);
        }
    }

}
```

This produces an output:

```
1
2
12
20
20
43
51
```

Comment: All answers were equally useful. I ticked the one with most votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bug**

On the array **`{ 3, 1, 4, 5, 2 }`**, the result will be **`{ 3, 1, 2, 4, 5 }`**. In order to fix this, in the inner **`for`** loop change

```
int comparisons = 1;
```

to

```
int comparisons = 0;
```

**API**

The Java coding conventions dictate that sorting routines are declared **`static`**, return nothing (have type **`void`**), and provide the version of the routine that can sort a particular subarray within an array.

Also, you might prefer to declare the constructor of **`BubbleSort`** as **`private`**, since that object does not do anything of interesting on its own.

**Algorithm**

Your algorithm runs always in \$\Theta(N^2)\$, whereas the actual bubble sort runs in \$\Theta(N)\$ on almost sorted input. Refer to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) for pseudocode that is more adaptive.

**Printing an integer array**

Instead of

```
for (int iterations = 0; iterations < numbers.length; iterations++) {
    System.out.println(numbers[iterations]);
}
```

you can easily write

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(yourArray));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I believe this algorithm is O(n^2) if you read the wikipedia. As far as I learnt, it is O(n^2) but can be optimized to O(log n) in some scenarios.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf There is no sorting algorithm that may be "optimized" to \$\mathcal{O}(\log n)\$; best case is no better than \$\Omega(n)\$.

Comment: If you look at wikipedia, there's an $O(log n)$ algorithm using `repeat-until`

Comment: @HassanAlthaf Doing exactly what in \$\mathcal{O}(\log n)\$?

Answer (score 1):

I think the two biggest design problems are:

- `temporary`, the temporary variable you use in `sort`, should be a local variable in the `sort` routine, not a member variable.
- `sort` should be static.

There are times when it makes sense to have some sort of `BubbleSortEngine` class whose instances are *objects that can perform a bubble sort*. This is typically when the algorithm might need access to some precomputed data, or maybe to acquire resources that will be reused through several invocations of the algorithm, or hold configuration options, or is keeping track of performance metrics, or other such things. (but this pattern has its own advantages and disadvantages and there are other patterns that can be used to achieve that effect)

However, this implementation is very much not one of those times.

---

Making `temporary` a local variable will likely result in a performance increase. It would also allow multiple threads to safely invoke `sort` concurrently.

Similarly, making `sort` static will increase performance. Not *directly*, but because the current design will tempt an application to create new `BubbleSort` objects all the time whenever it needs to perform a sort.

Answer (score 1):

[Javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html)

---

```
public class BubbleSort {
    private int temporary;
    public int[] sort(int[] numbers) {
```

There is no need that this is an instance class, a static utility class is very fitting for such tasks. Also, the `temporary` variable should be declared inside the function, not on a class scope.

---

```
for (int mainIterations = 0; mainIterations < numbers.length; mainIterations++) {
```

I like that you've used a full name instead of `i`, I like that. However, `index` would be more fitting and shorter.

---

```
this.temporary = numbers[comparisons];
```

`this` is unnecessary at this point.

---

```
public int[] sort(int[] numbers) {
    ...
    return numbers;
```

Your function takes an `int` array and returns an `int` array, this is very confusing. Without any further documentation a user would/could assume that you clone the given array and return a different one. Instead you modify the given one and return it. Which is cute if you try to create a "fluent" API but is here very confusing.

Either clone the given array and return that clone or do not return anything at all.

---

Otherwise this looks quite clean, nicely done.

Comment: What do you mean clone the given array? It will still return an int array.

Comment: Yes, but it won't modify the original one. `int[] toSort = new int[numbers.length]; System.arrayCopy(numbers, toSort, 0);` or some such.

Comment: Yes. I am aware. The array is passed by value, therefore, its a fresh new copy of the passed array.

Comment: No, no, damn no. What you gave the impression that arrays are passed *by value*? They are passed *by reference*, like everything else, with the exception of primitive types. Arrays are not primitives.

Comment: Oh @Bobby I see. My bad.